# Does IMDB have a list of the highest-rated TV programmes?

Tags: imdb

IMDB has a [list of the films](http://www.imdb.com/chart/top) its users have given the highest ratings, but i've seen TV programmes with even higher ratings. Is there a similar list for those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to get such lists on IMDB [by searching](http://www.imdb.com/search/title):

- [Highest rated programmes (English)](http://www.imdb.com/search/title?languages=en&title_type=tv_series&num_votes=5000,&sort=user_rating,desc)
- [Highest rated episodes (English)](http://www.imdb.com/search/title?languages=en&sort=user_rating,desc&title_type=tv_episode)

They now link to a similar search from  the **TV** menu.

Answer (score 1):

[**Best/Worst "TV mini-series"**](http://www.imdb.com/chart/tvminiseries)

[**iCheckMovies**](http://www.icheckmovies.com/) helps you keep a personal list of movies you have seen and liked.
This site is API for IMDB.
 You can try browsing through lists for TV shows

Answer (score 1):

For TV shows information (ratings, cast, summary, etc) I use [TV.com](http://www.tv.com/). Each episode is rated, and you can see a [list of top shows](http://www.tv.com/shows/multibrowse/?tag=page_nav;multibrowse), and even filter them by genre, decade, and network.

Comment: Nice. Although I don't agree with the ratings on TV.com as much as IMDB, I think it's the closest i'll get.

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to find this through IMDB. I found a [site](http://the-best-tv-shows.com/) that claims to do exactly what you ask, but i cannot vouch for its validity, so keep that in mind if you visit it.

Comment: Since Arrested Development is on top spot, it must be legit.